# Issue with package-lock.json while publishing the project

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm trying to publish my project, and constantly get the same error in logs:

Would you have any idea how to fix that?

```html
18 error Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true add D:...\main\backend\package-lock.json
18 error The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
18 error package-lock.json
18 error Use -f if you really want to add them.
19 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Where and how are you publishing it ? Is package-lock.json in a gitignore file ? (it should not)

Comment: Hi @Bulsky, for the first question, normally I run a builAll.sh script, I'm trying to publish it on Central/Main repository. For the second question, yes it the package-lock.json is mentioned in .gitignore.To

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete `package-lock.json` its not necessary, so much so someone went to the effort to ignore it via the `.gitignore` file. A new one will be generated each time the project is rebuilt anyway.